# Mantener el valor de la variable al abrir un modal

Tags: php, css, laravel, bootstrap

Tengo una tabla en la que a cada fila le paso unas variables a través de un foreach.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando le doy a 'Delete' se abre un modal, que tiene el primer valor de la tabla, da igual si hago click en el botón delete de la fila con el ID 5, que me pillara el valor del ID 1.

El código es este:

```
<tbody>
     @foreach ($admins as $key => $admin)
      <tr>
        <td class="idadmin tdcenter"><p id="margindata" class="tdmenuadmin">{{$admin->id}}</p></td>
        <td class="nameadmin"><p id="margindata" class="tdmenuadmin">{{$admin->name}}</p></td>
        <td class="emailadmin"><p id="margindata" class="tdmenuadmin">{{$admin->email}}</p></td>
        <td class="actionsadmin tdmenuadmin">

         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deletemenuadmin" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formdeleteadmin" id="margindata">Delete</button>

         <div id="formdeleteadmin" class="modal fade" role="dialog"> <!-- DIV TO SHOW THE CREATE PROJECT FORM 1 START HERE-->

         <div class="modal-dialog" style="background-color:#23517F;">

         <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#23517F;">

            <div class="modal-header">

            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

            <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:black;">{{$admin->id}}¿Estas seguro de borrar al administrador?</h4>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <a href="{{ route('admin.admins') }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">No</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.admins.destroy',$admin->id)}}">
                        <input type="submit" value="Si" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
                        {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="closemodal">Close</button>

            </div>

         </div>

       </div>

     </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Cuando le doy al Delete me muestra este modal: (esta recortado)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si le doy a si va a la ruta que indica el código y ejecuta la función del controlador, la función es esta:

```
 public function destroyAdmin($id) //Eliminar la informacion de un admin
    {
        $admin = Admin::find($id);
        $admin->delete();
        Session::flash('success','El admin ha sido eliminado con éxito.');
        return redirect()->route('admin.admins');
    }
```

¿Como puedo hacer que al abrir el modal, me mantenga el ID de la fila?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que está pasando en tu caso es que siempre estas abriendo la misma modal `#formdeleteadmin`, recuerda que un id es único e irrepetible en el sitio y cuando por alguna razón lo repites el código siempre va a interactuar con el primero que encuentre ignorando los demás.

Aprovecha los índices de tu foreach para generar id únicos así:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deletemenuadmin" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formdeleteadmin_{{ ($key + 1) }}" id="margindata">Delete</button>

<div id="formdeleteadmin_{{ ($key + 1) }}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

Comment: Hola Camilo, con tu código no se me llega a abrir el modal. Sabes que puede ser?

Comment: Wow que extraño, revisa por medio del inspector que si halla generado de forma correcta los id y que comillas y estructura estén bien

Comment: Al estar dentro de un foreach, no haría falta el +1, quedaría así: `data-target="#formdeleteadmin_({{$admin->id}})"` y entonces en el inspector de elementos si que pilla un id diferente en cada uno, pero sale este error: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #formdeleteadmin_(1)` y no se llega a abrir el modal.

Comment: A claro también lo puedes hacer con `$admin->id`, lo de `$key + 1` era para que nunca empezara en 0, ahora como lo estas haciendo realmente te debería de quedar así: `data-target="#formdeleteadmin_{{$admin->id}}"` no necesitas los ()

Comment: Cierto, ahora no da ningun error en consola pero tampoco se abre el modal..

Comment: No ? Que raro,ya verificaste que `data-target` y `id` tengan el mismo valor? con la excepción de que `data-target` debe comenzar en `#`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67288/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-camilo-vasquez).

Comment: @Bender Hola Camilo muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me sirvió.